# Collapse function in the columns

Tags: r

I need to collapse the values in B:

```
A      B
1      xyz
2      opi
1      abc
```

I need the below output:

```
A  B
1  xyz / abc
2  opi
```

Answer (score 2):

`aggregate(your_data_frame[2], your_data_frame[1], paste, collapse = " / ")`

Answer (score 0):

`tidyverse` approach using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- read.table(text = "A      B
1      xyz
2      opi
1      abc",header  =TRUE)

x %>% group_by(A) %>% summarise(B = paste(B, collapse = " / "))

## A tibble: 2 x 2
#      A B        
#  <int> <chr>    
#1     1 xyz / abc
#2     2 opi
```